# Is it possible to use swipe.js with video elements?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, swipe, swipe.js

I have a slider which has one slide that contains a video element. Everything works fine except for swiping on the video, which does absolutely nothing.

I imagine this is because the video element is "hijacking" the input, but is there a way around this?

Comment: I've searched around but haven't been able to find an answer to this question, just others asking the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried placing a transparent div over the video element?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I have not because the user still needs to be able to control the video (play/pause, scrub, etc.). Thank you for the suggestion though.